# Como puedo guardar una tabla y que el resultado se muestre en otro formuario?

Tags: php, html, mysql

no soy tan buena con php y quiero entenderlo. Como puedo guardar una tabla y que el resultado se guarde en la tabla principal. En la primer imagen, esta la parte de la tabla principal al darle click a **Agregar** manda otra pantalla, al momento de ingresar los datos quiero que al guardar los muestre en la tabla principal. Como puedo lo puedo hacer?

[image: imagen1]

[image: imagen2]

Comment: No se entiende muy bien la pregunta. Una vez llenado el formulario de la segunda imagen, donde quieres que aparezcan los datos?

Comment: Podrías generar una consulta SELECT donde te traiga esa información y pintarla en una tabla en la tabla principal.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es obtener los datos que has introducido en tu base de datos, simplemente haces una consulta, los almacenas en variables y los muestras donde tu quieras. Un ejemplo (en este caso uso PDO pero la idea es la misma en todos los casos):

```
$consulta = "SELECT usuario, fecha, contenido FROM tabla_usuarios WHERE usuario = 'Mayra Zurita'";

$resultado = $base -> prepare($query);
$resultado->execute(array());

//aqui haces el volcado de los datos de la consulta en variables
while($row = $resultado -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $usuario = $row['usuario'];
    $fecha = $row['fecha'];
    $contenido = $row['contenido'];

{
```

Ahora simplemente haces un `echo` de las variables allí donde quieras. Si deseas mostrarlo en un formulario puedes mostrarlo mediante un `echo` de todo el formulario o incluir este script en tu formulario html. Para ello simplemente en la pagina de tu formulario incluyes el script

```
<?php include('nombre_script.php'); ?>
```

Y muestras los datos mediante las variables anteriores. En cualquier parte puedes incluir:

```
<?php echo $usuario; ?>
```

Y se mostrara el nombre del usuario que has seleccionado mediante la consulta a la base de datos.
Si quieres incluir la información dentro de un `<input>` puedes hacerlo asi:

```
<input type="text" title="Nombre de usuario" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>" >
```